# ng-mocks: What is ".point"?

Tags: angular, mocking, jasmine, ng-mocks

I have seen this code in the docs:

```
const fixture = MockRender(TargetComponent);
expect(fixture.point.componentInstance).toBeDefined();
```

But I noticed, we can do `fixture.componentInstance` also, so without the point. I searched the docs but I didn't find an answer. What exactly does ".point" do? When to use it, when to not use it?

Answer (score 0):

The `.point` property in Angular testing refers to the `DebugElement` that wraps the component insteace.

The `debugElement` provides access to the component, directives and elements inside the component's template.

So the `fixture.point` return the `DebugElement`, while `fixture.componentInstance` return the actual component instace.

Some key differences:

- `fixture.point` allows you to query elements in the template using things like `.query()` and `.queryAll()` You can not do this with `fixture.componentInstance`.
- `fixture.componentInstance` allows you to access methods, properties and other things on the component class directly.

---

When to use `.point`:

- When you need to test elements in the component's template. For Example - finding a button element to click.
- When you need to access to directives in the template.

---

When to use `.componentInstance` directly:

- When testing methods or properties on the component class.
- When you don't need access to the template and just want to the component instance.

---

So in summary:

- Use `.point` when you need to access the template or directives
- Use `.componentInstace` When testing the component class members directly.

---

I hope this will help you. If you need more clarification then please let me know. Cheers